# How to update all fields from one table to another table in the same database using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update, create-table, insert-into

There are 2 tables in the same database with the same structure. I want to copy all data from one table to the other table using mySQL. The source table may have the same, less or more number of rows of the destination table.

I tried searching. I found 2 approaches:

Approach #1

```
TRUNCATE destination;
INSERT INTO destination SELECT * FROM source
```

Approach #2

```
DROP TABLE destination;
CREATE TABLE destination SELECT * FROM source
```

Isn't there any other approach involving UPDATE?

Comment: Update is for changes to existing records. You aren't changing the existing records, so your option is then INSERT.

Comment: Are you trying to consolidate records in 'desination'?

Comment: @MichaelGardner The destination is actually an old copy of the source.

Comment: Mysql has `REPLACE` which is a simplified version of SQL `MERGE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** I don't think so.

You can do `Insert`

```
Insert into destination
(
column_1,
column_2,
....
)
SELECT 
column_1,
column_2,
....
FROM source
```

**`Note:` No. of columns mention in destination = No. of columns mention in source**

By the **approach #1** will not work always.

and **approach #2** will always work

Comment: I have to ask why #1 won't always work?  Assuming there are no changes to table structure.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Because when you transferring data columns from source to destination **No. of columns mention in destination = No. of columns mention in source**

Comment: TY, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.